# Необходимо добавить кнопки в консоль по заданным координатам

Tags: java, swing

Как решить ошибку компиляции в строках 28, 29

```
    Frame.add(panel);
    Frame.setVisible(true);
```

---

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Component;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    public Main() {
        setName("Forum");
        // Определяем разрешение экрана монитора
        Dimension sSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ().getScreenSize ();
// Задаем размер
        setSize (sSize);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        Graphics g = m.getGraphics();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,50));
        panel.add(button);
        Frame.add(panel); //----------28
        Frame.setVisible(true); //----29
    }
}
```

Comment: а можно чуть подробнее?

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь обратиться к методам `add()` и `setVisible()` статически, исправлением будет замена
 `Frame.add(panel); Frame.setVisible(true);` *на* `m.add(panel); m.setVisible(true);`

---

Этим можно ограничиться, но я не удержался и заодно дополнил ваш код:

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public DrawPane dpane;
    public JButton btn;
    public DrawPane draw;

    public Main() {
        setName("Forum");
        setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false); // Запрет изменения размера окна

        dpane = new DrawPane();
        setContentPane(dpane);

        btn = new JButton("Button");
        btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
        dpane.add(btn);
    }

    private class DrawPane extends JPanel { 
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            // Операции с графикой
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { // По стандарту Swing должен запускаться в специальном потоке
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Main m = new Main();
                m.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Дальнейший код...
    }
}
```